# how to change the logging level of tensorboard?

Tags: logging, tensorboard

I can't find such option in the launching parameter of tensorboard. When I list all the flags what I found was like this:

```
logdir      --> .tensorboard/log_2019-06-30_18-33-18_952122
host      --> 
port      --> None
purge_orphaned_data      --> True
reload_interval      --> 5.0
db      --> 
db_import      --> False
db_import_use_op      --> False
inspect      --> False
version_tb      --> False
tag      --> 
event_file      --> 
path_prefix      --> 
window_title      --> 
max_reload_threads      --> 1
reload_task      --> auto
samples_per_plugin      --> 
debugger_data_server_grpc_port      --> -1
debugger_port      --> -1
master_tpu_unsecure_channel      -->
```

In operation it has logging level set to "WARNING" & log message directly printed out on stdout, as a result I saw a lot of unnecessary messages when writing complex models, like this:

```
I0630 18:33:19.152284 140581946894080 _internal.py:122] ::ffff:127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jun/2019 18:33:19] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
I0630 18:33:19.335198 140581946894080 _internal.py:122] ::ffff:127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jun/2019 18:33:19] "GET /font-roboto/oMMgfZMQthOryQo9n22dcuvvDin1pK8aKteLpeZ5c0A.woff2 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
I0630 18:33:20.419392 140581806262016 _internal.py:122] ::ffff:127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jun/2019 18:33:20] "GET /data/plugins_listing HTTP/1.1" 200 -
I0630 18:33:20.422904 140581212772096 _internal.py:122] ::ffff:127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jun/2019 18:33:20] "GET /data/environment HTTP/1.1" 200 -
I0630 18:33:20.424074 140581221164800 _internal.py:122] ::ffff:127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jun/2019 18:33:20] "GET /data/runs HTTP/1.1" 200 -
I0630 18:33:20.428111 140581204379392 _internal.py:122] ::ffff:127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jun/2019 18:33:20] "GET /data/experiments HTTP/1.1" 200 -
I0630 18:33:20.490971 140581204379392 _internal.py:122] ::ffff:127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jun/2019 18:33:20] "GET /font-roboto/RxZJdnzeo3R5zSexge8UUZBw1xU1rKptJj_0jans920.woff2 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
I0630 18:33:20.519970 140581204379392 _internal.py:122] ::ffff:127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jun/2019 18:33:20] "GET /data/plugins_listing HTTP/1.1" 200 -
I0630 18:33:20.522117 140581221164800 _internal.py:122] ::ffff:127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jun/2019 18:33:20] "GET /data/environment HTTP/1.1" 200 -
I0630 18:33:20.531321 140581212772096 _internal.py:122] ::ffff:127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jun/2019 18:33:20] "GET /data/runs HTTP/1.1" 200 -
I0630 18:33:20.533931 140581221164800 _internal.py:122] ::ffff:127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jun/2019 18:33:20] "GET /data/experiments HTTP/1.1" 200 -
I0630 18:33:20.709606 140581221164800 _internal.py:122] ::ffff:127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jun/2019 18:33:20] "GET /font-roboto/d-6IYplOFocCacKzxwXSOJBw1xU1rKptJj_0jans920.woff2 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

How do I get rid of them?

Comment: Figure anything out on this? This message is blowing up our logs on Jenkins.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing that I got to work was turning off logging for the whole program. I hope there is a more elegant solution, but for now it keeps those annoying refresh notices out of the way:

`logging.disable(logging.ERROR)`

Hope this helps!

(Tensorboard team, please add a verbosity flag or something similar)