# Set log level of Tensorboard

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

I am starting Tensorboard from within my application using following code:

```
from tensorboard import program
tensorflow_dir = os.path.join(parameters.model_dir, "train")
if not os.path.exists(tensorflow_dir):
    os.mkdir(tensorflow_dir)
tb = program.TensorBoard()
tb.configure(argv=[None, '--logdir', tensorflow_dir, '--port', str(parameters.tensorboard_port)])
tb.launch()
```

Tensorboard is started correctly and I can use it as I want to.
However the console is overflowing with log generated by Tensorboard everytime anything is reloaded.
I only found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56829286/how-to-change-the-logging-level-of-tensorboard) question from 2019 but did not find any newer information.

Does anyone know if it is possible by now?

Thank you!